# How can I get the type of an object from an EF EntitySet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have created an EF convention that sets a schema name for a class based on the interface it implements directly or indirectly.

```
public class TableNameConvention<T> : IStoreModelConvention<EntitySet>
{
    private readonly string SchemaName;

    public TableNameConvention(string schemaName)
    {
        this.SchemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public virtual void Apply(EntitySet entitySet, DbModel model)
    {
        // Get the name of the Entity
        string name = entitySet.Name;

        // Check TEntityType Assembly for entitySet type
        Type type = typeof(T).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();

        // Check if type was found
        if (type != null)
        {
            // Check if type implements Type Parameter and if so, set schema
            if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)) entitySet.Schema = SchemaName;
        }

        entitySet.Table = FormatName(name);
    }
```

This works fine 95% of the time. However, if there is another class with the same name anywhere in the Assembly, it'll return the default. I can change that to FirstOrDefault, but there's still no guarantee the first one is the one I'm actually looking for.

I know that without the fully qualified name, it's never going to be 100%, but does anyone have any suggestions to help improve the chances of getting the right type?

**UPDATE**

I changed the following:

```
Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                       .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == typeof(T).Namespace)
                       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(name));
```

It'll only work if the derived class is in the same namespace as the base class, though. So if anyone has any other suggestions, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no way to get the Entity's actual `Type` directly from an EF `EntitySet`, at least not in the Storage Model.

To make the code above work, I updated the class as follows:

```
private readonly string SchemaName;
private readonly string Namespace;

public TableNameConvention(string schemaName, string @namespace)
{
    this.SchemaName = schemaName;
    this.Namespace = @namespace;
}
```

and then updated where method on the Linq query to get the type from the AppDomain

```
Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                   .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == this.Namespace)
                   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
        // Check TEntityType Assembly for entitySet type
        Type type = typeof(T).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x == entitySet.GetType()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: That does not work. The `entitySet` variable refers to an object of type `EntitySet`, not the actual type of the underlying class it represents.